# Gridview.builder with Firebase realtime database and futurebuilder

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

Coming from Firestore, I am a little bit struggling how to receive data from Firebase real time database. I just want a nice grid view of images which are loaded from the realtime database.

```
Error: flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
flutter: Class 'DataSnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
flutter: Receiver: Instance of 'DataSnapshot'
```

I guess it's index related. No idea how to correctly map it within a list.

```
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new FutureBuilder(
            future: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                .reference()
                .child('messages')
                .child('1551276762582')
                .orderByChild('messagetype')
                .equalTo('1')
                .once(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.data != null) {
                  return new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new GridView.builder(
                          // itemCount: item.length,
                          gridDelegate:
                              new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return GridTile(
                                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                    imageUrl: snapshot.data[index]['imageUrl']
                                        .toString()));
                          },
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return new CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              } else {
                return new CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I could solve it with the following code. Again, I have to say that the Firebase documentation really lacks, which is quite disappointing, since Firebase is a great tool. Moreover, I do not understand, that there is no documentation on 'How to use Firebase with Flutter' (we are talking about both Google products.) Notwithstanding, here is the working code for anyone, who likes to use Streambuilder with Gridview.builder with the Realtime Database in Flutter:

```
StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .reference()
                  .child('messages')
                  .child(groupId)
                  .orderByChild('messagetype')
                  .equalTo(1)
                  .onValue,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  if (snapshot.data.snapshot.value != null) {
                    Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snapshot.data.snapshot.value;
                    List<dynamic> list = map.values.toList()
                      ..sort(
                          (a, b) => b['timestamp'].compareTo(a['timestamp']));

                    return GridView.builder(
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 3),
                      itemCount: list.length,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Container(
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
                                        imageUrl: list[index]["imageUrl"])),
                              );
                            },
                            child: CachedNetworkImage(
                              imageUrl: list[index]["imageUrl"],
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                        child: Center(
                            child: Text(
                      'Es wurden noch keine Fotos im Chat gepostet.',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.grey),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    )));
                  }
                } else {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              })),
```

Answer (score 1):

Something that I do that helps me solve issues, is by explicitly turning snapshots into Maps the following way.

```
Map yourModel = Map.from(datasnapshot);
```

also many times when handling null data or so on I have to turn the asyncSnap value that comes from the future Builder into a Datasnapshot from firebase in the following way

```
Datasnapshot snap = asyncSnap.data;
```

then handle for snap being null

```
if(snap.value!=null){}
```

Hope this helps! if you need help send me a message